# Was it Moses or Aaron who performed the signs in front of the Israelites in Exodus 4:30?

Tags: exodus, referent-identification, moses

Exodus 4:29-30

[29]Then Moses and Aaron went and assembled all the elders of the sons of Israel;
[30]and Aaron spoke all the words which the Lord had spoken to Moses. He then performed the signs in the sight of the people.

It seems the signs that are being referred to in the above text had been performed by Moses at mount Horeb.

But what is a little bit baffling is that the subject of the above text seems to be Aaron not Moses

It's not clear who performed these signs in front of the Israelites?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moses performed the signs.  Aaron was Moses' messenger / mouth.

> *"15 And thou shalt speak unto him, and put words in his mouth: **and I will be with thy mouth, and with his mouth,** and will teach you what ye shall do.  16 **And he shall be thy spokesman unto the people:** and he shall be, even he shall be to thee instead of a mouth, and thou shalt be to him instead of God.  17 **And thou shalt take this rod in thine hand, wherewith thou shalt do signs.**"*  (Ex. 4:15-17, KJV)

Ex. 7:1, *"And the Lord said unto Moses, See, I have made thee a god to Pharaoh: and Aaron thy brother shall be thy prophet."* (KJV)

Moses did the signs, and Aaron spoke.